# Tab view not working after updating PrimeFaces5.1 to PrimeFaces 5.2

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions

I am working on a web application which is developed on JSF 2.2 and primefaces 5.1, now I have updated it to PrimeFaces 5.2 and primefaces-extensions 3.2.0.

While testing, I found that tab View is not working properly. when I am clicking on other tabs to open it, it is not opening.

while troubleshooting I found following error:

1. Widget for var 'widget_mainform_j_idt75' not available!
2. Uncaught TypeError: e.addOnshowHandler is not a function

and I also notice that, when I click on tab, it will update url like follows

https://localhost:8443/mypp/#mainform:j_idt75:j_idt78

so it added **#mainform:j_idt75:j_idt78**

Comment: Check if you have by accident, you still two PF jars in your project. And code examples would help to.

Comment: i am using maven so there is no double pf jars

Comment: Hmmmm depends…  sometimes jars remain if you work from an ide. Please do an exlicit check

Comment: Are you manually including jQuery in the page?